# Django Installation Error :

Tags: django

Trying to create the first project. First got the below error when I ran,

django-admin.py startproject mysite

then I tried,

django-admin.py

Also symlinked the path and its in the path. But I still get the error.

. 
. 
.
 File "/Users/Satha/django-trunk/django/bin/django-admin.py", line 7, in 
    execfile(**file**)   File "/Users/Satha/django-trunk/django/bin/django-admin.py", line 4, in 
    from pkg_resources import require; require('Django==1.5.dev20120720114244')   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    requirements = list(requirements)[::-1]  # set up the stack   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2438, in parse_requirements
    yield Requirement(project_name, specs, extras)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2465, in **init**
    self.unsafe_name, project_name = project_name, safe_name(project_name)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1113, in safe_name
    return re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9.]+', '-', name)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 231, in _compile 
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: How did you install django? Are you using the dev version?

Comment: I used this, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#installing-development-version

Comment: Unless you are trying to work with development features you should remove that and use the stable release version.

Comment: Ok thanks! Is there an easy way to remove this version and install the new version.

Comment: Did you even install it with python setup.py in the first place or were you just running it right away? If you installed it, it would be in your system site-packages

Comment: I used pip, just the first two steps in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#installing-development-version

Comment: Cool. pip is usually the safe bet. It checks versions and dependencies, and also supposts uninstall and upgrade options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have some specific reason, you should probably not be using an unstable dev version of django (1.5). Though I am not exactly sure why you are having problems even with the dev branch, as it installs fine for me and creates a project equally as easily.

I recommend trying to first remove the dev version, and then install django via `easy_install` or `pip` which will get you v1.4.  [Installation Instructions here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/install/#installing-an-official-release-with-pip)

If after installing django 1.4, if you still have this issue, try creating a [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html), which will make an isolated environment in a directory, and then install django in that.